# ROS Installation, Unable to locate package ros indigo

Tags: ros, rosinstall, ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I followed this ROS installation tutorial (wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu)
unfortunately at Desktop full install following error appeared.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

How can I solve this problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233873/ros-installation,-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo/) by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on 2016-05-08**:
Did you remember to do a "sudo apt-get update" after setting the source list and keys?

**Comment by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on 2016-05-08**:
yes sure :)
1.2 , 1.3, and at Desktop Full install I m having this problem.

**Comment by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on 2016-05-08**:
What version of Ubuntu are you running?

**Comment by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on 2016-05-08**:
ubuntu 16.04 LTS on x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indigo is not available for 16.04 (I tried myself last week too :D). Notice the following line in the installation tutorial:

> Setup your computer to accept software
> from packages.ros.org. **ROS Indigo ONLY
> supports Saucy (13.10) and Trusty
> (14.04) for debian packages.**

That means indigo can not be found in the package source that we previously added to our list. Note the "$(lsb_release -sc)" when we add it to the source list. This allows it to only look for ros versions compatible with the linux release info.

There may be a way to install Indigo on 16.04 but I am not aware of it and it is not officially supported so you may run into issues down the line.
If you absolutely need Indigo, I would suggest installing 14.04. Or, if you absolutely need 16.04, there is supposed to be a new ROS release this month. Actually, maybe it's already available, check [here for installation.](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)

---

Originally posted by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) with karma: 253 on 2016-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on 2016-05-09**:
Thanks alot. so now I am heading to 14.04 :)